# Should I use "I" in a resume summary statement?

Tags: resume

I saw both on the web but I don't known which is "better".

I used to write things like:

> I am currently working as...
>
> I am a **versatile** and **creative** professional who enjoys learning new things.

Should I say something like:

> Working as...
>
> **Versatile** and **creative** professional who enjoys learning new things.

Comment: I'd steer away from having a summary statement in my resume at all.  That's what cover letters are for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I use “I” in a resume summary statement?

**I recommend never using personal pronouns anywhere in a resume.**

While it's perfectly reasonable to use "I" and "me" in a cover letter, your resume is different. If you started using "I", you would have to include it so many times that it would become annoying to the reader.

In the US it is generally recommended that personal pronouns be completely omitted. Your second example appears more appropriate.

A quick Google search for "using personal pronouns in resume" shows similar thoughts.

Comment: Agreed - it's fairly obvious that "I" am the subject of the resume in question - and have a bullet (or other style) list of sentences all starting with "I" is grating for those of use who read these things

Answer (score 0):

You should never refer to yourself in the first person in your CV.  While most of your CV can omit any references and use point form of the tasks, skills and technologies (for example) you used in a job, using the *third person* is something you can do in your executive summary.

For example, my CV starts with the following:

> Jane S is an IT professional with over 19 years experience as a data specialist,  solution architect, analyst and software developer.  She has worked in various industry sectors including the financial, mining, manufacturing and telecommunications industries, and for local, state and federal government departments.

Speaking in the third person can give an air of authority when talking about yourself, as it's like a formal introduction someone else may give.  Think of it as how you would like to be introduced as a keynote speaker at a big conference :)

Comment: That paragraph is more suited to a cover letter (if sending out a resume) or a bio section on the website if just posting the resume to be read - and not part of the resume itself - not sure if third person works in either case - it would make it seem like someone other than you has written the paragraph.

Comment: @HorusKol I have it as the executive summary on the first page of my CV, then a list of experiences in point form.  It works just fine for me :)

Comment: Fair enough - but I'd probably skip over it if it was on my desk...

Comment: @HorusKol Interesting.  It's very common here, maybe it's just a cultural thing.